# webページを完全保存

Tags: vba

皆様のお力をおかしください。

vba操作でwebページを丸ごと保存したい。
（htmだけの保存ではない。）

完全保存できる方法はありますか？（htmのファイルとfilesのフォルダができるようにです）

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかも。[VBAでインターネット上のファイルをダウンロードする方法をまとめてみました。](https://www.ka-net.org/blog/?p=4855), [三流君VBAでIE操作 InternetExplorer.Applicationを操作する](http://www.ken3.org/cgi-bin/group/vba_ie.asp), [No.120 URLDownloadToFile APIを使用してWebからファイルをダウンロードしてみた](http://www.ken3.org/vba/backno/vba120.html), [VBAのスクレイピングを簡単楽にしてくれるSelenium](https://excel-ubara.com/excelvba4/EXCEL_VBA_401.html)

Comment: htm形式でHTMLコードを取得できるのですが、コードをtextファイルで出力したいです。

Comment: 「コード」とは何を指していますか？ ちなみにhtm形式のファイルは、拡張子が`.htm`なだけで、メモ帳やエディタで開けばテキストとして中身が見えるはずです。名前を付けて保存するとかファイルコピー等の際に拡張子を`.txt`にすればダブルクリック等でもテキストとして扱えるようになるはずです。

Comment: @kunif .htmを.txtで表示すると、ネストで<!DOCTYPE html >が入っている箇所が省略されて、親要素のみしか表示されません。

Comment: 保存時や結果確認時にどんなツールで何をどうやったか、その省略されている、というのがどのように見えているか、本来ならどう見えていて欲しいか、といったことの詳細を追記してみてください。答えが得られやすいでしょう。

Comment: 「@kunif .htm」って、何ですか？　このサイトを見ている人に、user12141129さんがuser12141129さんのPC上で見ている内容を知ることが出来るとでも思っているのですか？

Comment: 恐らくブラウザでのページ保存で「すべての要素」として保存したのと同じ形式になることを想定しているのかなと思いますが (HTML以外は "タイトル_files" フォルダにまとめられる)、textファイルで出力したいについてはもう少し詳しい説明が必要かなと。